# Proper way of customizing JQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm basically trying to achieve is to customize JQuery dialog.

Consider I have a snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  var dialogAddPartDiv = $('#dialogAddPart');
  
  $('#showDialogButton').click(function() 
  {
     dialogAddPartDiv.dialog('open');
  });
  
  dialogAddPartDiv.dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     buttons:
     {
       'Save' : function(){}
     },
     beforeClose : function(event) 
     {
       if(!confirm("It won't be saved. Continue?"))
       {
         return false;
       }
       else 
       {
       }
     },
     width:500,
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content 
{
    border: 2px solid #05788d;
}

.ui-widget-content 
{
    border: 3px solid #05788d
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #222222;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>


<button type="button" id="showDialogButton">+Show Dialog</button>

<div id="dialogAddPart">

<table>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:100%;" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:100%;" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>


</table>

</div>

</body>
```

I've tried to customize it using CSS in order to change border color, but it doesn't seem to work. I actually also need to customize "Close" and "Save" buttons, but it even looks much harder problem(for example, when I try to apply make **background: transparent** in the **.ui-widget-header** in order to get rid of this nasty gray bar on the top it doesn't work as well. The only one way to make it work is **display:none** in **.ui-dialog-titlebar**, but it causes "Close" button to disappear which is not good in my case). What is the right way of customizing all that?

Comment: Have you tried applying !important to your custom css?

Comment: No, I haven't how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some changes into your code. In script i have added one new class as parent clas that's customizeDialog, updated css to header and save button using parentclass i have overided the old css with new one.

Hope it will useful to you. Thanks!

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var dialogAddPartDiv = $('#dialogAddPart');
    
  $('#showDialogButton').click(function() 
  {
    dialogAddPartDiv.dialog('open');
  });
    
  dialogAddPartDiv.dialog(
  {
    autoOpen: false,
 modal: true,
 buttons:
 {
   'Save' : function(){}
 },
 beforeClose : function(event) 
 {
   if(!confirm("It won't be saved. Continue?"))
   {
     return false;
   }
   else 
   {
   }
 },
 width:500,
  });
  $('.ui-dialog').addClass('customizeDialog');
});
```

```css
   .ui-widget.ui-widget-content 
{
    border: 2px solid #05788d;
}

.ui-widget-content 
{
 border: 3px solid #05788d;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #222222;
}

/* Customize dialog css */
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.customizeDialog{
 border: none;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 35px rgba(190, 184, 184, 0.65);
}
.customizeDialog .ui-widget-header, .customizeDialog .ui-button{
 background-color: transparent;
 background-image: none;
 color: #fff;
 border: 0; 
 padding: 0;
}
.customizeDialog .ui-button{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.customizeDialog  .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
 background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>


<button type="button" id="showDialogButton">+Show Dialog</button>

<div id="dialogAddPart">

<table>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:100%;" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:100%;" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>


</table>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. In jQuery Ui dialogue there is already css given by the `jQuery-ui.css`. You need to replace it with your new css. If you want override default CSS then you can use !important after you css. For example `color:#000` if you want to override this you can use `color:#fff !important;` like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var dialogAddPartDiv = $('#dialogAddPart');
  
  $('#showDialogButton').click(function() 
  {
  dialogAddPartDiv.dialog('open');
  });
  
  dialogAddPartDiv.dialog(
  {
 autoOpen: false,
 modal: true,
 buttons:
 {
  'Save' : function(){}
 },
 beforeClose : function(event) 
 {
  if(!confirm("It won't be saved. Continue?"))
  {
  return false;
  }
  else 
  {
  }
 },
 width:500,
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content 
{
    border: 2px solid #05788d;
}

.ui-widget-content 
{
 border: 3px solid #05788d
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #222222;
}

.ui-widget-header {
    background: red !important;
    border: none !important;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget{
background:none;
}
button.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>


<button type="button" id="showDialogButton">+Show Dialog</button>

<div id="dialogAddPart">

<table>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:100%;" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test:</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="text" style="width:100%;" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Test</td>
<td><input type="text" size="40" value=""></td>
</tr>


</table>

</div>

</body>
```